# What would cause /var/log/syslog to only be written to when executing rsyslog -d?

Tags: 13.04, rsyslog

I have one system where /var/log/syslog is written to as expected, and another system where it can't be written to unless I stop rsyslog service and run it manually with "rsyslog -d".

How do I debug this problem?  I tried deleting everything in /etc/rsyslog.d/,  recreating it.

I tried removing and reinstalling rsyslogd

```
apt-get remove rsyslogd and apt-get install rsyslogd ubuntu-minimal
```

and then checked that service is running but only the other logs are being updated, not /var/log/syslog.

I am just trying to have the default configuration of rsyslog working.

I noticed that /var/log/syslog is root:adm instead of syslog:adm.  The log files that are syslog user work ok.   If I make /var/log/syslog syslog:adm, then it starts working.  Perhaps the permissions are broken somehow.  Doesn't logrotate change the permissions / create these files again later?  Not sure if the fix will be permanent or not.

Answer (score 0):

You've already determined that it's a file permissions issue, and that the user specified for the service in */etc/rsyslog.conf* is unable to write to the log file.  However your logon user (presumably root) does have access when run interactively.  Here's an example of the section of *rsyslog.conf* which specifies the service user configuration:

```
#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog
```

As for logrotate, you may configure how the syslog files are managed, see */etc/logrotate.conf* and */etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog*.  Here's a sample:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

On my test system, *logrotate.conf* also contains:

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create
```

From *man logrotate*:

```
create mode owner group
    Immediately after rotation (before the postrotate script is run) the log file is created (with the same name  as  the  log
    file  just  rotated).   mode specifies the mode for the log file in octal (the same as chmod(2)), owner specifies the user
    name who will own the log file, and group specifies the group the log file will belong to. Any of the log file  attributes
    may  be omitted, in which case those attributes for the new file will use the same values as the original log file for the
    omitted attributes. This option can be disabled using the nocreate option.
```

So in my case, the *create* option determines how the new file attributes are set, because the options specified in */etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog* do not override that global setting.  When *mode*, *owner* and *group* are not specified, logrotate uses the same values as the original log file.

Hopefully, that gets you started.  Good luck!